# gingerbread emulator support for opengl es 2.0

Tags: android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Android Emulator support OpenGL ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455783/does-the-android-emulator-support-opengl-es-2-0)

I read  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455783/does-the-android-emulator-support-opengl-es-2-0)  that android sdk 2.3 has emulator support for opengles 2.0.

However after upgrading my eclipse environment with the latest sdk I fail to find any support.
To be honest I can't find where in the documentation that it claims to be supported.

I have a small 2.2 targeted app that runs on the galaxys s 2.2, but cannot run it on any emulator.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Check the accepted answer to [the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455783/does-the-android-emulator-support-opengl-es-2-0).  It points out that, while SDK 2.3 has support for the Java bindings to OpenGLES2, the emulator provides an implementation only for OpenGLES1, not OpenGLES2.