# does android emulator support OpenGl ES2.0.?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Does Android emulator support OpenGl ES2.0? I run the code but Eclipse gives me the following error:

> Unfortunately adb has stopped

Comment: Refer to this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455783/does-the-android-emulator-support-opengl-es-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Android Emulator support OpenGL ES 2.0 as described in this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html). You have to select the “GPU emulation” option from the hardware menu when creating a new AVD if you want to take advantage of this feature.